# How to make icons and images for Android app?

Tags: android, image, icons, screen-resolution

I think this might be something not a trouble for iPhone app since the screen size are sort of same.

But android has so many devices with different screen size. How do the images fit well for different screen sizes?

I mean, does the app have to stock for the same icon with many versions for different width and height so to install for different screen-size smart phone.

Or, ( which I don't think so ) the images and icons are scaled propotionally on the phone to suit for looking on the phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been documented very thoroughly in [Android Developers Icon Design Guidelines.](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html)

Different density devices load their assets from different folders if available.

```
res/...
    drawable-ldpi/...
        finished_asset.png
    drawable-mdpi/...
        finished_asset.png
    drawable-hdpi/...
        finished_asset.png
    drawable-xhdpi/...
        finished_asset.png
```

You should use `mdpi` as the baseline.

```
ldpi = 120 dpi (Low density screen)
mdpi = 160 dpi (Medium density screen)
hdpi = 240 dpi (High density screen)
xhdpi = 320 dpi (Extra-high density screen)

                     ldpi            mdpi            hdpi            xhdpi
Launcher Icon Size   36 x 36 px      48 x 48 px      72 x 72 px      96 x 96 px
```